# Why is Angular number pipe output different from Intl.NumberFormat.format()?

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, angular6

I'm experiencing different output when using number pipe compared to a custom `Intl.NumberFormat` event thought I have specified the locale to use.

Let's say I have the number `x = 1234.56` and I want to output it.

Number pipe returns 1,234.56

```html
{{x | number:'1.2-2':'de-CH'}}
```

`Intl.NumberFormat` returns 1’234.56

```js
twoFractionDigitNumberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-CH', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 });
```

```html
{{twoFractionDigitNumberFormat.format(x)}}
```

I've set up jsfiddle to show the different output: https://jsfiddle.net/2xs4t50y/1/

I know I could create a custom pipe which replaces the `,` with a `'`, but I'd like to know from where this difference comes and ideally how I can fix it besides with string replacements. If I'm informed correctly, the number pipe also uses the internationalization api under the hood.

Comment: The difference comes from the fact that Angular doesn't use the Intl API (unless you use a very old version of Angular). https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Comment: Alright, thanks @JBNizet for your quick reply. I added the angular6 tag to clearify that this behavior is version dependent.